# asp.net master page displays the list of my folder

Tags: html, asp.net, master-pages

Firstly I was encountering appcmd set config problem, as it's shown below image[image]

I run this code-appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true - in the command prompt and the problem is solved, however now this page pops up. I can not truly run my application, could you help me to solve this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the web.form.page as an start page, otherwise it displays the folder of the project.

Answer (score 1):

First, undo the changes that you have done to web.config. A secure application must not show the list of files.

Then, right click on the project name --> Add new item --> Select a new webform with master pager --> Set the name to "Default".

Masterpages cannot work without any web forms. They are just layout.

Comment: There are aspx pages. What makes you think adding another one will solve the problem?